# Out Of Memory Exception While Getting AlbumArt

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, expandablelistview, bitmapfactory

Here i have created expandable list view which is having group row for Artist and in child it shows all albums for artist with album art. But It throws out of memory exception.

Here Is my code to get the Image :

```
public static Bitmap getArtwork(Context context, int album_id) {

        ContentResolver res = context.getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);
        if (uri != null)
        {
            InputStream in = null;
            try 
            {
                in = res.openInputStream(uri);
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, sBitmapOptions);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
            {
                // The album art thumbnail does not actually exist. Maybe the user deleted it, or
                // maybe it never existed to begin with.
            } finally
            {
                    if (in != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            in.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
             }
        return null;
    }
```

And for creating child album list i have done this :

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>> createChildList() {
    for (int i = 0; i < songsListData.size(); i++) 
    {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> secList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        String s[] = new String[]{songsListData.get(i).get("artistname")};
        String whereClause = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST + " = ? ";

        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,null ,whereClause,s,null);

        if (cursor == null) 
        {
              //Query Failed , Handle error.
        }
        else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) 
        {
             //No media on the device.
        }
        else
        {            
              int albumName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM);
              int id = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);
              int songcount = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS);

              for(int j=0;j<cursor.getCount();j++)
              {
                    String Name = cursor.getString(albumName);
                    Integer albumid = cursor.getInt(id);                        
                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    bitmap = getArtwork(context, albumid); //calling function
                    if(bitmap == null)
                    {
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.wallpaper);
                    }   
                    HashMap<String, Object> album = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    album.put("albumName",Name);
                    album.put("albumId", albumid);  
                    album.put("image", bitmap);  //storing image
                    album.put("songcount",cursor.getString(songcount) + " song");
                    secList.add(album);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
               }                  
           }
           cursor.close();   
           albumData.add(secList);
    }
    return albumData;
}
```

what should i do to handle out of memory exception.?? Pleaze give me some solution. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debug your code and trace heap size when it goes unexpectedly up 
that must be due to increase image Size 
you can use the [Document](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) to Get an idea that how Android calculate the Image Size

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: should i decrease the height and width of bitmap image before storing in hashmap??

Comment: yes 1st read the document and then debug your code and check heap size how it is increasing after that if you need to decrease the size of the bitmap you can  use the above code